# MySQL Table Join: One record, two fields, id in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to join two tables, producing a result where the IDs in the 2nd and 3rd columns of table2 are replaced by the corresponding `name` values from table1:

```
table1:
  id - name
  ---------
  1 -  Sam
  2 -  Ben
  3 -  Nick

table2: 
id      name1           name2        upvote   downvote

1    1(id of Ben)    3(id of Nick)    150       8
```

So my goal here is to join these tables and produce:

```
1 -  Ben  -  Nick  -  150   - 8
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: You must join the first table to the second *twice*, once for each of the ids (`SELECT ... FROM table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1a ON ... JOIN table1 t1b ON ...`).  It is no coincidence that that also gives you two separate `name` columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Join is needed, See more :
[MySQL Joins Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT 
table1.id,table1.name,
table2.name2,table2.upvote,
table2.downvote 
FROM `table1`
INNER JOIN `table2`
ON
table2.name2 = table1.id
```